# fprof stop tracing and output "Empty trace!"

Tags: erlang, trace

I start tracing some pids by `fprof:trace([start, {procs, [Pids]}])` and I stop tracing by `fprof:trace(stop)` after 100s. It output `"Empty trace!" executing fprof:profile()`, hence `fprof:analyse({dest, Path})` output a empty file. All calls of these functions return `ok`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing it correct.

Can you verify that your Pids are actually doing anything during your 100 seconds?
Have you specified the Pids correctly?
Look at the number of reductions your Pids do using the command

```
i().
```

in the Erlang shell.

Comment: I get these pids by whereis(ProcName) and filter undefined.So Pids should be corect.Can you tell me it'll output "Empty trace!" in what case? thank you.

Comment: I looked at the source code for fprof.erl. It only prints out "Empty trace!" when the trace is empty. If there are other problems during the trace, it prints other error messages. I suggest again that you look at the number of reductions your Pids are doing during the 100s. I suspect they are doing no reductions at all and then you get an empty trace. Is this the case?

Comment: Could you also post your code for starting the trace? Maybe the problem is on getting or filtering the PIDs